# Is there a way of passing a model into a template without a class based view

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

My question is can I use a function view to pass in a model inside my template to be iterated through. This is how my model looks like:

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey( User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    itempicture = models.ImageField(upload_to="images",blank=False)


    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    
    
    about = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    

    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

How can I write a function based view to pass in my database just like a class based (list view)?

Comment: Share your actual template file in the question by editing, it's not clear in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [`all()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#all) but if you want custom filtered queryset which we usually do by overriding [`get_queryset()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_queryset) method in [`ListView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) so you can use [`filter()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#filter) method in the following way:

views.py

```py
def home(request):
    listings=Listing.objects.all() #Give the default queryset as ListView
    filtered_listings=Listing.objects.filter(user=request.user) #Give the queryset for current logged in user which can be achieved by overriding "get_queryset()" method in "ListView".

    return render(request,"some_folder_name/some_filename.html",{'listings': listings})
```

Then you can simply iterate any of the queryset in template (Assuming, you know the logic of urls.py and template file).

Comment: I used the same type of template tag as for a class based view but it is not working

Comment: {% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {% for list in listings %}

    <div class="items">
      <img src="{% static list.itempicture %}" alt="" />
      <div class="Info">
        <h1>{{list.title}}</h1>
        <p>{{list.about}}</p>
      </div>

      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

Comment: @JACOB Edit your question with this template file.

Comment: @JACOB What do you really want? Share your template file and relevant files in the question by editing, in comment these are not understandable. I did it with function based, what do you want, do you want it from ListView?